# Open Relink dialog via button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to MS Access 2016 and came across a supposedly minor issue but I couldn't figure it out yet.

I'd like to use a button on a form which opens the dialog "*Relink Lists to New Site*". The relinking will be done manually but opening it should happen by a button-click.

The manual way to open it would be:

- right-click on any table
- More Options
- Relink Lists...

I thought of some vba code or a macro to connect to the button.
Does anyone know if this is actually possible and if yes, any hints?
I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Try recording a macro to record your keystrokes and see what code is generated.

Comment: I thought about it too but as far as I know Access does not offer this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this button can also be found in the ribbon, you can use the idMso to invoke it:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AccessRelinkLists"
```

You can find a listing of all idMso identifiers used in Office 2016 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745. This contains an Excel file for each Office program with a listing of all possible controls and their identifiers.

Note that this button is context-dependent, and if you invoke it in a context where it's unavailable (e.g. an Access database without SharePoint lists) it will error.